How do I solve the AuthenticationError on MicrosoftGraph API?
I am using the Microsoft Graph API to send and get messages, but when trying to make the /messages or the /sendMail request, I'm getting the following error:
"code": "AuthenticationError",
"message": "AADSTS500014: The service principal for resource 'https://outlook.office365.com/' is disabled. This indicate that a subscription within the tenant has lapsed, or that the administrator for this tenant has disabled the application, preventing tokens from being issued for it. Trace ID: fb68ddac-e1f1-452d-827b-3451f0c0c101 Correlation ID: 1aed6368-ba68-45dc-a5ec-f369f3d3b951 Timestamp: 2024-04-29 10:53:25Z",

I am getting correctly the accessToken, and the office account that I'm logging in is active because I tried to log in and send messages from Thunderbird and It worked.
For more information, I've checked the Allow Users to Login in the MicrosoftAzure directory and is set to Yes.

I worked on it last thuesday.
In Postman I have the following Post request :
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/youpi@mail.com/sendMail

I also got 2 headers :

Authorization wich contain your type of token (Bearer) plus your token
Content-Type wich is set to application/json

In my body I got :
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "test",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "html",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "saymyname@mail.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "ccRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "iamthedanger@mail.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "false"
}

If you got something similar the problem should be in your Azure Active Directory.
In Azure Active Directory I just put the permission to Mail.Send for Application type.
If this don't help you, I suggest you to look at the Graph Collection in Postman, it was really useful to me. (link here)
Have a nice day !

I have been following the Graph Collection of postman step by step, I can get the profile request and it works fine, but when getting messages or sending mails, It appears the error that i mentioned in my question.

Is it possible to have a look at your request and your Azure Active Directory configuration ?
